# JQuery Checkbox double action in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

i found hard to create a multi functional checkbox, i want when a user check it then, the display of a div it becomes from none to block, and when the user uncheck the checkbox it becomes none.

i tried to create a double condition,

```
$("#customCheck1").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked") || document.getElementById("Reload").style.display = "none") {
    $('#lblauto').text("Auto Reload ON")
    document.getElementById("Reload").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    $('#lblauto').text("Auto Reload OFF")
    document.getElementById("Reload").style.display = "none";
  }
})
```

but it don't work.

these are the codes which I have to use:

Html(Checkbox):

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" id="checkasd">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1" id="lblauto"><span>Auto Reload OFF<span></label>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$("#customCheck1").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#lblauto').text("Auto Reload ON")
    document.getElementById("Reload").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    $('#lblauto').text("Auto Reload OFF")
  }
})
```

i use bootstrap v4.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery `toggle`. Create a class and initially hide the `Reload` div. Then use `toggle` to hide/show

```js
$("#customCheck1").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#lblauto').text("Auto Reload ON")

  } else {
    $('#lblauto').text("Auto Reload OFF")
  }
  $("#Reload").toggle('display')
})
```

```css
.display {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" id="checkasd">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1" id="lblauto"><span>Auto Reload OFF</span></label>
</div>

<div id='Reload' class='display'>Reload Div</div>
```

Comment: the checkbox, check it

Comment: On checking it , the text is changing and reload div is appearing

Comment: yeah, i need when you uncheck, then the display is none

Comment: @brk, your code works. I'm not sure what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with this line `if ($(this).is(":checked") || document.getElementById("Reload").style.display = "none")` where the single `=` should be `===`

The $().on method can also use the event in the callback so you do not need to access the DOM again

```
$("#customCheck1").on("change", function(e) {
  var isChecked = e.target.checked;
  if (isChecked) {
    $('#lblauto').text("Auto Reload ON");
    $("Reload").css('display', 'block');
  } else {
    $('#lblauto').text("Auto Reload OFF");
    $("Reload").css('display', 'none');
  }
})
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? I am able to make it work so maybe there is more going on

Comment: when i try to uncheck the checkbox doesn't do this